# How do I create a variable based on the user and input from user?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to populate the `From` with the current user logged on and `To` with input from the user. I am new but here is my code. I was wondering is there a built in function for sql, or how would any of you people go about handling this?

```
<pre>
insert into dbo.tbl_Messages
(          [DateTime],  [From],     [To],       CC,     ID,         [Subject], [Message],         [Priority], [Read], Read_DateTime, Reply_Req, [Sent], Study_ID )
values (    getDate(),  @userID,    @userID,    ' ',    @userID,    'test',    'test',       1,          1,      NULL,          0,         0,      0)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored proc on the lines of below:

```
CREATE PROC DoStuff(@UserID int)
AS
BEGIN
insert into dbo.tbl_Messages
(          [DateTime],  [From],     [To],       CC,     ID,         [Subject], [Message],         [Priority], [Read], Read_DateTime, Reply_Req, [Sent], Study_ID )
values (    getDate(),  SUSER_NAME(),    @userID,    ' ',    @userID,    'test',    'test',       1,          1,      NULL,          0,         0,      0)

SELECT ('Insertions Done!')

END
```

`SUSER_NAME()` returns the current user's username.